# Sending multiple emails at once using Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4

I managed to make it work sending email to one user at a time but not to multiple users at one. Although i have tried many ways, below is a sample code using which I am trying to send multiple emails.

```
 if (isset($_POST['searchbutton'])) {             $data = $query->where('blood_type', '=', "$search")                             ->Where('state', '=', "$state")->get();              if (isset($POST['emailbutton'])) {                 foreach ($data as $row)                     Mail::send('emails.notify', array('name' => 'Name'), function($message) {                          $message->to($row->email, $row->name)->subject('Hello');                     });             }         }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestion of changes assuming that all the user will receive the same email, means you won't be customizing each email with user's name:

```
if (isset($_POST['searchbutton'])) {
  $data = $query->where('blood_type', '=', "$search")
    ->Where('state', '=', "$state")->get();

  $emails = $query->where('blood_type', '=', "$search")
    ->Where('state', '=', "$state")->lists('email');

  if (isset($POST['emailbutton'])) {
    Mail::send('emails.notify', array(), function($message) use ($emails) {
        $message->to($emails)->subject('Hello');
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual error here is that the variable `$row` is not in the scope of your closure. To correct this, you need to use the `use` keyword. i.e.

```
foreach ($data as $row){
    Mail::send('emails.notify', array('name' => 'Name'),
        function($message) use ($row) {
            $message->to($row->email, $row->name)->subject('Hello');
        }
    );
}
```

You can read more [about PHP closures here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php).